# v-if or v-show is not working although the variable shows false on the template

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a video upload inside a composable and I am trying to hide the video player so it only shows once a file has been uploaded, but it's not working an inside the template I have a v-if on the container holding the video player but no matter what it keeps displaying even though the variable controlling the display is false.

Here is the Vue component used for the form display:

```
<script setup>
// imports
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useFoundersStore } from "@/stores/founders";
import axios from "axios";
import { useCharacterCount } from "@/composables/utilities";
import { useImageHandling, useVideoHandling } from "@/composables/utilities";

// store
const store = useFoundersStore();

// data
const account = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("account"));
const topost = ref(false);
const can_view = ref("");
const can_comment = ref("");

// state
const createPostForm = ref(null);

// emits
const emit = defineEmits(["closeform"]);

const fields = ref({
  errors: [],
  image: "",
});
var files = [];

function closeForm(data) {
  emit("closeform", data);
}

// utilities
const { comment, counter, limitReached, useCountChars } =
  useCharacterCount(2000);
const handleImage = useImageHandling(fields, store);
const handleVideo = useVideoHandling(fields);

// methods
async function createPost() {
  if (createPostForm.value) {
    const form = createPostForm.value;
    const canViewInput = form.elements["can_view"];
    const canCommentInput = form.elements["can_comment"];
    const bodyInput = form.elements["body"];
    const imageInput = form.elements["image"];
    const videoInput = form.elements["video"];
    const takeToPostCheckbox = form.elements["taketopost"];

    if (
      bodyInput.value == "" ||
      canViewInput.value == "" ||
      can_comment.value == ""
    ) {
      store.messages.push("Please complete all fields");
      setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
    }

    let data = {
      can_view: canViewInput,
      can_comment: canCommentInput,
      body: bodyInput,
      image: imageInput,
      video: videoInput,
    };

    console.log(createPostForm.value);
  }
  try {
    // if (fields.value.image === "") {
    //   formdata.delete("image");
    // }
    // if (hasVideo.value === false) {
    //   formdata.delete("video");
    // }
    // const response = await axios.post("/api/v1/posts/c/", data);
    // if (response.status === 201) {
    //   store.messages.push("Post created successfully");
    //   setTimeout(() => {
    //     store.messages = [];
    //   }, 3000);
    //   if (topost.value) {
    //     closeForm(response.data.post_id);
    //   } else {
    //     closeForm();
    //   }
    // }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="component fixed z7 p5 wb br5" id="createPost">
    <div class="closePopup floatL relative" id="closePost" @click="closeForm">
      X
    </div>
    <h2 class="AddPostTitle mb10">Create a Post</h2>
    <form
      ref="createPostForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      class="whitebg p10 br5 p15"
    >
      <fieldset class="mb10 b1 br3">
        <select
          name="can_view"
          id="post_can_view"
          class="pointer"
          v-model="can_view"
        >
          <option value="" selected disabled>Who can view?</option>
          <option value="EV">Everybody can view</option>
          <option value="CO">Only connections can view</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="mb10 b1 br3">
        <select
          name="can_comment"
          id="post_can_comment"
          class="pointer"
          v-model="can_comment"
        >
          <option value="" selected disabled>Who can comment?</option>
          <option value="EV">Everybody can comment</option>
          <option value="CO">Only connections can comment</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="mb10">
        <textarea
          v-model="comment"
          @input="useCountChars(2000)"
          name="body"
          placeholder="Max 2000 characters"
        ></textarea>
        <p :class="{ red: limitReached }" class="small">
          Character count: {{ counter }}/2000
        </p>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="imagesDisplay mb15">
        <div class="displayImage relative">
          <img :ref="handleImage.previewImg" class="postPreviewImg" />
          <img
            class="picClose absolute"
            src="../assets/img/close.png"
            v-if="fields.image != ''"
            @click="handleImage.removeImage"
          />
        </div>
        {{ handleVideo.hasVideo }}
        <div class="videoWrap" v-if="handleVideo.hasVideo"></div>
        <div class="videoPreview relative">
          <video :ref="handleVideo.videoPreview" height="200" controls></video>
          <img
            class="picClose absolute"
            src="../assets/img/close.png"
            v-if="handleVideo.hasVideo"
            @click="handleVideo.removeVideo"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        class="mediaButtons relative horizontal mb15 alignC around z3 b3 w30 auto br3"
      >
        <div class="imgButton relative mr20">
          <input
            type="file"
            name="image"
            class="addPic"
            accept="image/*"
            @change="handleImage.handleImage"
          />
          <div class="buttonImage absolute">
            <img class="picImg pointer" src="../assets/img/pic.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vidButton relative ml20">
          <input
            type="file"
            name="video"
            class="addVid"
            accept="video/*"
            @change="handleVideo.handleVideo"
          />
          <div class="buttonImage absolute">
            <img class="picImg" src="../assets/img/vid.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="toPost flex justC alignC mb20">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="taketopost"
          id="taketopost"
          class="mr5"
          v-model="topost"
        />
        <label for="taketopost" class="m0">Go to post upon saving</label>
      </div>
      <fieldset class="flex justC">
        <button
          type="button"
          id="createPostBtn"
          class="mr10"
          @click="createPost"
        >
          Create
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="cancelPostBtn"
          class="ml10 alt"
          @click="closeForm"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

and here is the composable with the video upload functionality:

```
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

export function useCharacterCount(limit) {
  const comment = ref("");
  const counter = ref(0);
  const limitReached = ref(false);

  const updateCounter = (text) => {
    counter.value = text.length;
    limitReached.value = counter.value > limit;

    if (limitReached.value) {
      comment.value = text.substring(0, limit);
    }
  };

  watch(comment, updateCounter);

  return {
    comment,
    counter,
    limitReached,
    useCountChars: (maxChars) => {
      limit = maxChars;
      updateCounter(comment.value);
    },
  };
}

export function useImageHandling(fields, store) {
  const previewImg = ref(null);

  if (previewImg) {
    const handleImage = (event) => {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      function isFileImage(file) {
        return file && file.type.split("/")[0] === "image";
      }

      if (isFileImage(file)) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          previewImg.value.src = e.target.result;
        };
        fields.value.image = file;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        store.messages.push("Only image files are allowed");
        setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
      }
    };

    const removeImage = () => {
      previewImg.value.src = "";
      fields.image = "";
    };

    return { previewImg, handleImage, removeImage };
  }
}

export const useVideoHandling = () => {
  const videoPreview = ref(null);
  const hasVideo = ref(false);

  const handleVideo = (event) => {
    hasVideo.value = true;
    const video = videoPreview.value;
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      video.src = reader.result;
    });
  };

  const removeVideo = () => {
    const video = videoPreview.value;
    video.value.src = "";
    hasVideo.value = false;
  };

  return { videoPreview, hasVideo, handleVideo, removeVideo };
};
```

The form works and i can upload a video and it previews but no matter what I cannot hide the player until the file is uploaded.
What am I doing wrong please and why is v-if not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is described here:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#caveat-when-unwrapping-in-templates

> Ref unwrapping in templates only applies if the ref is a top-level
> property in the template render context.

So you either use `v-if="handleVideo.hasVideo.value"` or

```
const {hasVideo, ...handleVideo} = useVideoHandling();

...

... v-if="hasVideo" ...
```

I guess this "strange" logic how to handle refs in templates has its sound reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much I will read the docs more thoroughly